# Xamarin.Forms Binding whole view inside a grid

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am currently training a bit of bindings and MVVM in Xamarin.Forms XAML.
I have a view with a grid and I want to bind a whole View to it as a child.

Further I am using ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms and their views, which I want to display.

Programmatically it is no problem with
`grid.Children.Add(MyView);`

But how can I achieve the same result with bindings in XAML?

Thanks in advance!

My Xaml in which the View should be binded to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ZxingNetMobileTemplate.ScannerView">
    <Grid BindingContext="{Binding .}" x:Name="test">
        
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTorchTapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>         
    </Grid>       
</ContentPage>
```

my Xaml.cs with the viewmodel:

```cs
 public partial class ScannerView : ContentPage
    {
        public CameraViewModel CameraViewModel { get; private set; }

        public ScannerView(IEnumerable<BarcodeFormat> formats = null)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = CameraViewModel is null ? CameraViewModel = new CameraViewModel(formats) : CameraViewModel;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            CameraViewModel.ScanAsync();
            //test.Children.Add(CameraViewModel.Scanner);
            //test.Children.Add(CameraViewModel.Overlay);
            SubscribeScanResult();
            CameraViewModel.Scanner.IsAnalyzing = true;
            CameraViewModel.Scanner.IsScanning = true;
        } 
}
...
```

and last but not least my viewmodel, where the properties "Scanner" and "Overlay" should be binded into the xaml

```cs
  public class CameraViewModel
    {
        public ZXingScannerView Scanner { get; private set; }
        public ZXingDefaultOverlay Overlay { get; private set; }
        public IEnumerable<BarcodeFormat> CustomFormats { get; private set; }
        public string ImgSource => Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android ? "thunder.png" : "Images/thunder.png";

        public CameraViewModel(IEnumerable<BarcodeFormat> formats)
        {
            CustomFormats = formats;
        }
...
}
```

Comment: Need more information. Do you have your customView with Grid where do you want to bind another view (I assume some zxing view) ?

Comment: Yes, I have the normal XAML file including its .cs. My Zxing thingies are inside a Viewmodel CameraViewModel. A grid is defined in the xaml where the ViewModel is binded to.

Comment: I will add more code in short

Comment: @puko I added the code

Comment: well why do you want to use binding when you set the CameraViewModel in code behind  ? Doesn't make sense for me to use binding, just access grid by x:Name and add the view.

Comment: in my opinion that is cleaner

Comment: Children grid property is not bindable. If you want to add some view into this collection via binding  you need to make custom control with some BindableProperty that will add your custom view in propertyChanged delegate of BindableProperty (btw in the same way grid.Children.Add(view)).

Comment: I will try it then, thanks

Comment: i will show you how .. wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241148/discussion-between-puko-and-patrick-schulz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make custom "Grid" like

XAML

```
<ContentView
  ....>
  <ContentView.Content>
     <Grid x:Name="Grid">
         .... here is your default content
     </Grid>
   </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

.cs

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class View1 : ContentView
{
      public static readonly BindableProperty CustomViewProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomView), typeof(View), typeof(View1), null, propertyChanged: OnCustomViewChanged);
    
      public View1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
      }
    
      public View CustomView
      {
          get { return (View)GetValue(CustomViewProperty); }
          set { SetValue(CustomViewProperty, value); }
      }
    
      static void OnCustomViewChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
      {
          //x:name Grid xaml
          //not sure if you want to clear grid before add new control
          //((View1)bindable).Grid.Children.Clear();
    
          ((View1)bindable).Grid.Children.Add((View)newValue);
      }
}
```

Then in your Xaml instead of Grid use View1 (in my case, plz pick some nicer name :)).

```
//not sure if you want to bind Scanner property
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ZxingNetMobileTemplate.ScannerView">
    <View1 CustomView="{Binding Scanner}">   
</ContentPage>
```

Note: It is not a good practice to have ViewModel that contains Views. Imagine that you want to use this ViewModel in a different application, let's say WPF. You can't because there is a dependency on Zxing.

Comment: hey, your code didnt work 1:1 for me since View1 derived from ContentView does not contain InitializeComponent() method nor .Grid in the event handling
I derive it now from Grid directly and add its children there

Comment: View1 contains InitalizeComponent and also Grid (it is name of Grid in Xaml). I did not want to derive from Grid. I wanted to hide Children property. Now when you will derive from Grid, Children property will be exposed

Comment: sent you a message into the chatroom from yesterday